# How to query two date fields, stored in a Wix collection, between two dates?

Tags: javascript, date, filter, velo

I'm trying to narrow down my search results by using a query function that uses two date fields in Wix.

Data are stored with the format MM/DD/YYYY in the collection.
Strangely, in Wix, it seems one should first reformat a value returned from a "datapicker". I tried to do so, but it was in vein.
Could you please help me to the problem of code.
My code is:

```
function search() {

let startingDatePickerValue = $w("#startingDatePicker").value;

let endingDatePickerValue = $w("#endingDatePicker").value;

wixData.query("Collection1")

        .contains("title", $w('#input11').value)        

        .find()

        .then(results => {

            $w('#repeater1').data = results.items;

            let searchResults = results.items;

            if (startingDatePickerValue !== null || endingDatePickerValue !== null) {                

                let yearValue = startingDatePickerValue.getFullYear();

                let monthValue = startingDatePickerValue.getMonth();

                let dayValue = startingDatePickerValue.getDate();

                let dateValue1 = new Date(yearValue, monthValue, dayValue, 0, 0, 0);


                let yearValue2 = endingDatePickerValue.getFullYear();

                let monthValue2 = endingDatePickerValue.getMonth();

                let dayValue2 = endingDatePickerValue.getDate();

                let dateValue2 = new Date(yearValue2, monthValue2, dayValue2,  23, 59, 59);


                let newQuery = results.query;

                newQuery

                    .ge("startingDate", dateValue1)

                    .le("endingDate", dateValue2)

                    .find()

                    .then((newQueryResults) => {

                        $w('#repeater1').data = newQueryResults.items;

                        let newQuery = results.query;

                        console.log(dateValue1, dateValue2)

                        return newQuery

                    })

            }

}
```

the returned dataVlue1, dataValue2 values are

Tue Jan 10 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0n00 (GMT+0n:00) Sat Jan 14 2023 23:59:59 GMT+0n00 (GMT+0n:00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to just change the dates in the collection to dates with times. There is a checkbox for including the time. That will let you do the comparison with JavaScript Date objects.